# 5v PCI to PCI-X or PCIe adapter?

Tags: pci, adapter, pci-express

We unfortunately have a very expensive ($10K) full-length 5 volt PCI card that we would like to use in the same system as another expensive PCI-X card.  As luck would have it, it seems that PCI-X is not backwards compatible with 5v PCI cards.  It would be a real shame to have to order a whole new server just to accommodate these two cards together.

Does there exist any internal converter/adapter that will allow one to place a full-length 5v PCI card into either a PCI-X or PCIe slot?  I've found an external expansion box that suits our needs but it's 1) External and 2) $1100.  The only internal adapters I've been able to find go from Low-profile PCI -> PCIe; nothing that seems to support full-height, full-length PCI cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StarTech](http://www.startech.com/) makes a couple:

[PCI->PCIe(1x)](http://www.startech.com/item/PCI1PEX1-PCI-to-PCI-Express-Adapter-Card.aspx)

[PCIe(1x)->PCI](http://www.startech.com/item/PEX1PCI1-PCI-Express-to-PCI-Adapter-Card.aspx)

These are pretty out-of-the-ordinary and if you're using a full-height, full-length card you're probably looking at some fabricating to get it to fit in a chassis while using one of these adapters.

Comment: Ya, those are the internal ones I found that I was talking about in my post.  The lack of other responses is making me think that I am SOL.

Comment: If you use any adapter with a full-height, full-length card you'd need to do some chassis modifcations at least, only becuase a card that size barely fit in a chassis as it is. :) You're probably going have to go new (as per your other question).

Answer (score 0):

You're not likely to find an adapter that fits inside your case and any sane way.  Full length, full height cards are just too big. That said, if you're willing to tolerate an external box, the StarTech [PEX2PCIE4L](http://www.startech.com/item/PEX2PCIE4L-PCI-Express-to-2-PCI-Full-Length-2-PCIe-Single-lane-Expansion-Box.aspx) ($399 MSRP) should get the job done. [PDF Spec Sheet](http://www.startech.com/Share/ProductSpecs/PDF/PEX2PCIE4L.pdf) and [PDF Manual](http://www.startech.com/Data/ProductManuals/PEX2PCIE4L.pdf).

It has a PCIe x1 card which attaches to the box via DVI-I (wtf?).  The box has two PCI-E x1 slots and two regular PCI slots.  The spec sheet says it supports 3.3V/5V and full length cards.  You can even get an [ExpressCard](http://www.startech.com/item/EC2PCI-ExpressCard-Connection-cable-For-PEX2PCI4.aspx) with the proprietary DVI-I connector instead of the included PCI-E x1 card.

[Amazon has it for $325](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002I9SK5S), cheaper than the $1100 box you mentioned (from Magma I assume).